# How to add incrementing values to string for every time string occurs in Stata?

Tags: regex, stata

I have a string variable named `talk`. Let's say I want to find all instances of the word "please" in `talk` and, within each row, add a suffix to each "please" that contains an incrementing count of the word.

For example, if `talk` looks like this:

```
"will you please come here please do it as soon as you can if you please"
```

I want it to look like this instead:

```
"will you please1 come here please2 do it as soon as you can if you please3"
```

In other words, "please1" indicates that it's the first "please" to occur, "please2" is the second, etc.

I have written some code (below) using regex and several loops but it doesn't work perfectly and, even I could work out the kinks, it seems overly complicated. **Is there a simpler way to do this?**

```
# I first extract the portion of 'talk' beginning from the 1st please to the last   
    gen talk_pl = strtrim(stritrim(regexs(0))) if regexm(talk, "please.+please")
# I count the number of times "please" occurs in 'talk_pl'
    egen count = noccur(talk_pl), string("please")
# in the loop below, x = 2nd to last word; i = 3rd to last word 
    qui levelsof count
    foreach n in `r(levels)' {
            local i = `n' -1
            local x = `i' -1
            replace talk_pl = regexrf(talk_pl, "please$", "please`n'") if count == `n'      
            replace talk_pl = regexrf(talk_pl, "please (?=.+?please`n')", "please`i' ") if count == `n' 
            replace talk_pl = regexrf(talk_pl, "please (?=.+?please`i')", "please`x' ") if count == `n'         
        }
```

Comment: not sure why the code in my post is colored the way it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str71 talk
"will you please come here please do it as soon as you can if you please"
end

// Install egenmore if not installed already
* ssc install egenmore

clonevar wanted = talk

// count occurrences of "please"
egen countplease = noccur(talk), string(please)

// Loop over 1 to max number of occurrences
sum countplease, meanonly 
forval i = 1/`r(max)' {
    replace wanted = ustrregexrf(wanted, "\bplease\b", "please`i'")
}
list

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1. |                                                                           talk        |
     |        will you please come here please do it as soon as you can if you please        |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
     |                                                                     wanted | countp~e |
     | will you please1 come here please2 do it as soon as you can if you please3 |        3 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is SO much simpler than what I was trying to do - thanks!!